# Find the Fourier series of rectified sine wave

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-series, indefinite-integrals

> Find the Fourier series of rectified sine wave $f(x) = \left( \sin x \right)^+$ (the non-negative part of sine function), i. e.,

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\sin x, \ \text{if} \sin x \geq 0.\\
0, \ \text{if} \sin x < 0.
\end{cases}$

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

$a_n = 0$ for $n \geq 0$, because $f$ is an odd function.

Let's calculate $b_n$.

$b_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int^{\pi}_{-\pi} \sin (x) \sin(nx) dx$

If $u = \sin(nx)$ and $dv = \sin(x) dx$, then $du = n \cos (nx) dx$, $v = - cos (x)$ and

$\int \sin (x) \sin(nx) dx = - \sin (nx) \cos(x) - \int - \cos (x) n \cos (nx) dx$

$= - \sin (nx) \cos(x) + \int \cos (x) n \cos (nx) dx$

If $a = \cos (x)$ and $db = n \cos (nx) dx$, then $da = - \sin (x)$, $b = \sin (nx)$ and

$\int \cos (x) n \cos (nx) dx = \cos (x) \sin(nx) - \int \sin (nx) \left( 
- \sin (x) \right) dx$

$= \cos (x) \sin(nx) + \int \sin (nx) \sin (x) dx$

but now I can't compute $\int \sin (x) \sin (nx) dx$. I would like to know how to calculate this integral. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why $f$ is an odd function?

Comment: $f$ is not odd, so $a_n$ is in general not $0$. I think using $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\bigl(\sin x + \lvert \sin x\rvert\bigr)$ makes finding the Fourier series easier.

Comment: @DanielFischer, how $f$ defined as you defined help me? I tried compute Fourier series of this $f$ and I find $a_n = b_n = 0$.

Comment: The Fourier series of $\sin x$ is _very_ simple. You don't even need any calculation to find it, you can read it off immediately. $g \colon x \mapsto \lvert \sin x\rvert$ is an even function, so its Fourier series consists purely of $\cos$ terms. You get those coefficients as $$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \lvert \sin x\rvert \cos (nx)\,dx = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \lvert \sin x\rvert\cos (nx)\,dx = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin x\cdot \cos (nx)\,dx$$ since $\sin$ is nonnegative on $[0,\pi]$. Now use $\sin a\cos b = \sin (a+b) + \sin (a-b)$.